# Create a List of existing Buttons

Tags: c#, arrays, button

l've 10  ten button on my forms ( 0 to 9) to simulate a calculator
    All my buttons are named like this `btnCalc0`,`btnCalc1`,`btnCalc2`,etc...

I want to create an array or list of these buttons to handle event but it's doesn't work because `btnCalc` doesnt exist`(btnCalc+x)`.

```
List<Button> lstBtnCalc = new List<Button>();
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
{
  lstBtnCalc.Add(btnCalc+x)); 
}

private void myClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = lstBtnCalc.IndexOf(sender as Button);
}
```

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF, or something else?

Answer (score 3):

You could populate your array with a loop (See ASh's answer). However, in doing so, you make the code harder to read. The primary test of good code is readable code, so avoid "clever" solutions and keep it simple. In this case, a simple, easy to read and maintain, way is:

```
List<Button> lstBtnCalc = new List<Button>
{
    btnCalc0, btnCalc1, btnCalc2, btnCalc3, btnCalc4,
    btnCalc5, btnCalc6, btnCalc7, btnCalc8, btnCalc9
}
```

Comment: Short and sweet answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Find method:

```
List<Button> lstBtnCalc = new List<Button>();
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
{
    var buttonName = string.Format("btnCalc{0}",x);
    var button = this.Controls.Find(buttonName);

    if (button != null)
    {
        lstBtnCalc.Add(button);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<Button> lstBtnCalc = null;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            lstBtnCalc = new List<Button>() { button1, button2, button3, button4 };


        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

a bit fluent:

```
 List<Button> lstBtnCalc =   this.Controls.OfType<Button>().Where(a => a.Name.StartsWith("btnCacl")).ToList();
```